# Why does my for loop skip some markers coordinates?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, for-loop, google-maps-api-3

I have this `for loop` that loops through an array (4 levels deep) to retrieve the lat and long coordinates of my marker positions. It seems to work fine however it skips the 5th, 8th and 9th coordinate. I would really appreciate any help or advice. Thank you.

```
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (i=0; i < categories.length; i++){
   for (j=0; j < categories[i].length; j++){
     for (var k = 0; k < categories[i][j].length; k++) {
       marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(categories[i][1][j][k]), 
      parseFloat(categories[i][2][j][k])),
      index:k,
      icon : categories[i][5][j][0]
    });
    //create marker categories
    marker.category = categories[i][6][j][0];//category[6][j][0]
    marker.setVisible(true);
    markers.push(marker);
    bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
    marker.setMap(map);
   }
  }
 }


 //the arrays
 var  categories = [category];
 var category = [
 names,
 lat_locations,
 long_locations,
 links,
 icons,
 icon_image,
 real_names,
];

  var lat_locations = [
  container_yards_locations_lats,
  truck_yards_locations_lats,
  terminals_locations_lats,
  new_developments_locations_lats,
  manufacturing_companies_locations_lats,
  warehouses_locations_lats,
  transport_companies_locations_lats,
  jettys_locations_lats,
  free_land_locations_lats
  ];

 var container_yards_locations_lats = [
 6.445638,
 6.447416
 ];

 var truck_yards_locations_lats = [
 6.452937
 ];

 var terminals_locations_lats = [
 6.4356407,
 6.432294,
 6.4433638,
 6.442223,
 6.4371918,
 6.4331848,
 6.433211,
 6.440850
];

 var new_developments_locations_lats = [
 6.450393
 ];

 var manufacturing_companies_locations_lats = [
 6.447272
 ];

 var warehouses_locations_lats = [
 6.446857,
 6.450077
 ];

 var transport_companies_locations_lats = [
 6.450675
 ];

 var jettys_locations_lats = [
 6.443349
 ];

 var free_land_locations_lats = [
 6.451843
 ];

 var lat_locations = [
 container_yards_locations_lats,
 truck_yards_locations_lats,
 terminals_locations_lats,
 new_developments_locations_lats,
 manufacturing_companies_locations_lats,
 warehouses_locations_lats,
 transport_companies_locations_lats,
 jettys_locations_lats,
 free_land_locations_lats
];


var container_yards_locations_lngs = [
 3.3111681,
 3.3113029
];

var truck_yards_locations_lngs = [
 3.3062503
];

var terminals_locations_lngs = [
  3.3330524,
  3.3555287
];

 var   new_developments_locations_lngs = [
  3.3031123
 ];

 var manufacturing_companies_locations_lngs = [
  3.3099291
 ];

 var warehouses_locations_lngs = [
  3.3082508,
  3.3089833
 ];

 var transport_companies_locations_lngs = [
  3.3090743
 ];

 var jettys_locations_lngs = [
  3.3159546
 ];

 var free_land_locations_lngs = [
  3.3017833
];

var long_locations = [
 container_yards_locations_lngs,
 truck_yards_locations_lngs,
 terminals_locations_lngs,
 new_developments_locations_lngs,
 manufacturing_companies_locations_lngs,
 warehouses_locations_lngs,
 transport_companies_locations_lngs,
 jettys_locations_lngs,
 free_land_locations_lngs
];
```

I feel it will be too much putting all the arrays here and those arrays are obviously not complete but this is the explanation:

> var  categories = [category];
>
> var category = [//contains 9 different categories];
>
> var "sub_category" = [//contains arrays that have multiple variables in
>   each];

Each category has an array that contains various variables. So to access the 
deepest variable you would need to reference it like so:

> categories[0][2][8][0]

Comment: Share the content of the array (or at least part of it)! Are all coordinates correct? What did you try to debug?

Comment: I have included part of the array. All the coordinates are correct. If I reference it directly like :categories[0][2][8][0], I get the exact coordinate I want. But I when I include the variables as in: categories[i][2][j][k], the 5th and 8th and 9th coordinates do not show on the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reference in the for loop is all wrong:

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (i=0; i < categories.length; i++){
   for (j=0; j < categories[0][i].length; j++){
     for (var k = 0; k < categories[0][i][j].length; k++) {
       marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(categories[i][1][j][k]), 
      parseFloat(categories[i][2][j][k])),
      index:k,
      icon : categories[i][5][j][0]
    });
    //create marker categories
    marker.category = categories[i][6][j][0];//category[6][j][0]
    marker.setVisible(true);
    markers.push(marker);
    bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
    marker.setMap(map);
   }
  }
 }
```

Code works fine now.